# OpenCl kernel code

Tags: c++, opencl

I am very new to OpenCL (started today). I am having a hard time in realizing the kernel code for adding numbers of an array in the following fashion: 
If A[]=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], then the sum should be sum[]=[4,10,16];

```
i.e, sum[i]=A[i]+A[i+2]; 
     i=i+3;
```

I have tried the following code but it does not seem to work.

```
std::string kernel_code =
        "   void kernel simple_add(global const int* A, global const int* B, global int* C){ "
        "   int x =0;"
        "   int i =get_global_id(0);"
        "   SUM[x]=A[i]+A[i+2];"
        "   i=i+3;
        "   x++;"
        "   }  ";
```

I am certain this is not the way to do it. Suggestions in this regard would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should calculate i as if the work item were the only one in the set. gid is the global id of the work item, and i needs to be three times that. You also don't need to modify gid or i after they are used. This is not optimal, but it will get you the correct answer.

```
void kernel simple_add(global const int* A, global const int* SUM){
    int gid = get_global_id(0);
    int i = gid * 3;
    SUM[gid]=A[i]+A[i+2];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !! The code yields correct results. After a bit of reading i realized that the global id of the work item need not be modified explicitly. Thanks for your support :)